# How can I bring a background GUI job to the front of my desktop?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, window, job-control, xdotool

In Lubuntu 18.04, I have many background GUI jobs running in a bash shell.
Among them, I have a evince process running in background:

```
$ jobs | grep evince
[29]   Running                 evince CurrentDBs.pdf &
```

I would like to bring its window to the front of  my desktop (in front of my current lxterminal window which runs the bash shell), but `fg 29` doesn't do so.

Why is that? Is it because job control of a shell has nothing to do with which window is in the front or not in the desktop environment (or X window system)?

How can I bring a background GUI job to the front of my desktop? 
[Can   xdotool be used to raise the window of a given process id to the front, even if the process runs a Windows program under Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060169/does-xdotool-not-work-with-any-windows-program?noredirect=1#comment1734922_1060169)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, xdotool will work

Here is how you can raise all evince windows to the front:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class evince windowactivate %@
```

I see no reason that it would not also works with Wine programs. Of course, you'll need to find the right name to call them. The command `xprop` may help.

Answer (score 0):

The `evince` is running in the backgroud in a subshell (pay your attention to trailing ampersand in the process executed). But since it's GUI app its window should be visible to you, since window close button pressing should terminate whole subshell process. If you don't see `evince` window while subshell backgroud process exists, it means a bug probably. There are two possibilities:

1. Try to find the hidden window somewhere (second desktop or press `Alt+Tab` or `Alt+Shift+Tab` to switch windows).
2. Kill the process manually with `kill` or just close shell which invoked subshell with `evince` to send  `SIGHUP` to the subshell.

Comment: Closing the shell you started a program from and backgrounded with `&` will not close the program. I start programs from terminals with `program & exit` all the time without the program closing automagically with the shell.